# Why is //*[1] different from (//*)[1]

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I created two files, `input.xml` and `formatter.xslt`.

input.xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="formatter.xslt"?>
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span></div>
```

formatter.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html><head></head><body>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//*[1]"/>
            ,
            <xsl:copy-of select="(//*)[1]"/>
        </body></html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I opened `input.xml` in Internet Explorer, and pressed F12. I saw the DOM tree was like:

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <div><span>1</span><span>2</span></div><span>1</span>
    ,
    <div><span>1</span><span>2</span></div>
</body></html>
```

Why did `//*[1]` and `(//*)[1]` copy different elements into the output document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `//*[1]` is `/descendant-or-self::node()/*[1]` while `(//*)[1]` is `(/descendant-or-self::node()/*)[1]` so the former selects all element nodes that are the first child of their parent while the latter selects only the first node selected by the expression in parentheses, that is it selects only the first of those element nodes that are a child of a parent node.

Comment: The fact that '//' isn't just '/descendant-or-self::' has been an endless source of confusion... Having a breadth-first walk available isn't a bad thing, but it's rarely what you actually want.